# Get full stop after align tag

Tags: align, punctuation

Say I am typing the following:

```
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= absuc \tag{First tag} \\
     &= abshgi \tag{Second tag}. 
\end{align*}
```

This outputs the following:
[image]

However, I am trying to find a way to get the full stop (period) AFTER the close bracket of the tag (my supervisor is very picky with regards to placement of full stops). How can I get it to do that?

Comment: Sorry for you. But it doesn't make any sense. :(

Comment: @egreg - I can't seem to think it's possible either :( . I guess I'll just have to "fake it" by manually inserting spaces instead of tags.

Answer (score 3):

I sympathize with you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\make@df@tag@@@}[2][]{%
  \gdef\df@tag{%
    \tagform@{#2\rlap{\hphantom)#1}}%
    \toks@\@xp{\p@equation{#2}}%
    \edef\@currentlabel{\the\toks@}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= absuc \tag{First tag} \\
     &= abshgi \tag[.]{Second tag}\label{X}
\end{align*}

\eqref{X}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The punctuation in the optional argument will be in the margin.